# About the list of all nodes in graph(python)

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx

I meet this question when I read about the python script of SCI2(Science of Science)software. Maybe what I want to ask is a simple python question.
I will show the SCI2 script first in the picture below. After that,I will write some codes. My question is why the codes in the picture can get list of all nodes by slicing method [:] but I can't.
[codes from SCI2 python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGZTs.png) Maybe the picture can not be shown, I write the important codes here. (the language is python)

```
# make a copy of the list of all nodes
nodesbynumworks = g.nodes[:]
```

What I wirte is:

```
import networkx as nx
g =nx.Graph()
g.add_node(1,size=11)
g.add_node(2,size=12)
a = g.nodes[:]
```

And this is my result:
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAV8x.png)
I just want to get the list of all nodes so that I can take some nodes from this list. And maybe I can change some attributes of some nodes.But I can't do that now. What I can think about is the reason that python2 and python3 are different in some place. I know this a a very pale explanation.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: What happens when you run your script? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: I am sorry.I forgot to show what happens when I run my script.My script is just create a simple graph with two nodes and try to get the list of them.What I received is:TypeError:unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: I think I don't know why the SCI2 python script can get a list of all nodes in graph g to use in the following codes but I can't do that in same code.The SCI2 python script is used for the visualization of the co-author network

Comment: what line causes the error?

Comment: I can't upload picture in the comment.But the error line is line 5:a = g.nodes[:]

Comment: You can edit your question to add information.  And rather than using a picture, it helps to copy and paste the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the list of keys, then try:

```
g.nodes().keys()
```

If you want the list of values, then try:

```
g.nodes().values()
```

Comment: I just want to get a list of all the nodes because I need to change some attributes of some nodes just like what the picture shows.The original idea is to get a visualization of co-author network.The SCI2 python script is an option that to be selected for our purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For SCI2, it appears to me that they have made a choice about how to represent graphs.  For them `graph.nodes` is a list (or perhaps it's a numpy array or something similar).  Thus `graph.nodes[:]` is a perfectly well-defined command.

You're using networkx for your graphs.  For networkx `graph.nodes` is something different.  In earlier versions of networkx, it is a function that returns a list of nodes, so `graph.nodes()[:]` will do what you want, but `graph.nodes[:]` doesn't make since because you're asking for a slice of the function, rather than a slice of the list it returns.  In later versions it is a NodeView.  I think your code might work in this version.  If not, then I'm fairly confident that `graph.nodes()[:]` still works.

[I don't have the newer version on the computer I'm using right now, so I'm not 100% sure.]

Comment: Actually, I don't know the earlier versions of networkx,but I think it may be the reason of version.Now,you have told me that,and SCI2 software is writed in python2 so the version of network is older too.If in SCI2 script it use something like graph_nodes rather than dot,that must be a list(or perhaps a numpy arrar).Just for the dot they use I have this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Never mind,I just want to think about something strang  but does matter at all sometimes.

Comment: I mean in my opinion,the dot '.' is only used for the method or function of a class.It is not like the underline '_' that can be used in the name of variable

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone.I have used a method to know something.

I used `print type(g)`and `print type(g.nodes)`and found something like the picture.
[the type of g and g.nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fun2w.png)
So this is created by Jython which combine python and Java and it is not an object of networkx.
Okay,now I can convince myself.

Thanks for everyone again!